# Best cycle to work provider?

Tags: commuter, uk

I'm looking at signing our work up to a Cycle to Work scheme in the UK. There are a lot of online reviews of the benefits of the scheme, but not much feedback on which are the best providers to go for.

Would anyone like to share their experiences with particular providers? Has their customer service been up to scratch?

Thanks very much.

Comment: This question may be closed since its primarily opinion-based and thus doesn't quite fit into the SE format.

Answer (score 2):

I run my own company, and therefore had ready access to this scheme since I was both the employer and the employee, but I actually decided against it altogether.

Now, this was a couple of years ago, so you'll need to check whether what I say still applies, but this is what I found:

You have a twelve-month agreement where essentially the company buys the bike, and you then pay £x per month to lease the bike off them. The "x" covers the cost of the bike, but there is a tax saving to be had.

But I think you need to look at what happens at the end of the twelve month period. My understanding is that the company, not the individual, actually owns the bike. So in order for "you" to end up owning the bike, you'd need to buy it from your company (i.e. more expense). And when I looked at it, HMRC (the UK Tax authority) were making noises about the company having to sell the bike at a "fair market price". In other words, its not reasonable to take a £1000 bike, then to say that after a year it is only worth £10, or some ridiculously small amount.

Now, as I say, this was a couple of years ago. At the time I decided that the scheme was a bit half-baked, and to steer clear of it.

But I think what I'd be looking for now is to see some clarity on what happens at the end of the twelve months, how much you would need to pay to actually make the bike yours. Whether there were now concrete guidelines in place, or whether it was all as woolly as it was when I looked.

I think if looking at the different providers, that would be my defining criterion.

Sorry, I know this probably doesn't directly answer your question, but hopefully it'll give you some idea of one line of questions to ask the different providers in order to allow you to make your own decision.

Comment: I don't think anything has changed, unfortunately, and the fair market value thing is an HMRC requirement so unlikely to vary between schemes.  What may vary is the time period during which you lease the bike (because you're not paying tax on the lease).  A longer lease would clearly also drop the resale value.  The other differentiator between schemes was that some offered a significant amount of vouchers towards accessories as a freebie.  Generally speaking it's more worthwhile if you're a higher-rate taxpayer buying a reasonably pricey bike.

Comment: There has to be easier ways to help employees purchase a bike. I know when I was a kid, my step-father's employer had a deal where they could purchase a computer through their work.  They got a great deal on the computers because they made such a large order, and they worked it out so the employees were able to pay it off with a small monthly deduction on their paycheque.  I'm sure something could be done for bicycles.  Talk to the employees and see how much demand there is for bikes, then talk to your local bike shop to determine what kind of discounts you could obtain on a large order.

Comment: @ChrisH yes I remember calculating that the more you spent, the better it worked out, subject to a limit I think of £1000. Above that, the company had to be licensed as a credit broker, which frankly was more hassle than it was worth. I avoided it completely by simply buying the bike through the company, thereby gaining the same tax advantages, but by leaving it as a company bike. Since it was used to travel pretty much exclusively between clients' offices, I could justify it. Until it got nicked.

Comment: @Kibbee it was a classic case of beware the small print. It was the "fair market value" that did for it. Also a lot of companies (e.g. banks etc.) were scared off by the fact that at the end of 12 months, they would potentially have all these second-hand bikes to dispose of. And since the idea was to get people commuting, there was also grief in the early days around the question "what if a guy buys a fancy bike through the scheme, just to save cash, but doesn't use it for commuting?" Fortunately HMRC realised this couldn't be policed, and dropped that particular requirement.

Comment: @Kibbee similar rules would apply to a tax-efficient scheme for buying computers, but employees can sometimes get good deals from computer firms of which their employer is a major customer without any tax implications.  Whether a company  could put enough business to a bike shop to get a significant discount is a different story - after all, there aren't many firms that buy many bikes.

Comment: @PeteH but at least it was on the company's insurance (or not yours anyway).  I know of people whose employers provide e-bikes for residential client visits round here, as strict parking rules with no exceptions even for health visitors etc. make cars impossible for them.

Comment: I'm sure if you went to you local bike store and told them you wanted to order 20-30 bikes, they would not hesitate to give you some kind of deal.  If they don't, take your business to the next guy. The savings won't be as good as with the other programs, but the employees will own the bikes outright, and it will be a much easier system to manage.  It can't hurt to try a few shops to see what kind of reaction you get.

Comment: @Kibbee I reckon you'd need to be responsible for at least 500 employees and probably many more to get that many bikes.  It's a guess based on the approximate proportion of regular cyclists (not just bike-commuters) where I've worked. Many cyclists are quite attached to the bikes they've got and wouldn't take the chance to upgrade, many non cyclists wouldn't even consider buying a bike.  You'd want to do it just before Christmas in that case and make sure kids bikes were included (as there's no requirement for commuting under this plan.

Comment: @ChrisH - Exactly, make it not only about commuting, but bikes in general. Sure, some people wouldn't use them for commuting, but the more people that have bikes the higher likelyhood that they would use them for commuting. Maybe some people don't want to commute but would rather just use it one the weekends and evenings for recreation.That wouldn't be such a bad thing.  Personally, I don't think making bikes more affordable will get more people commuting, because bikes are already very affordable anyway. So if people wanted to commute by bike, the price of the bike isn't what's stopping them.

Comment: I've been on the selling end of a company-bulk-buy like that, and I think the company also subsidised the bikes to some degree (our end was that they got a decent discount off retail, their staff could buy any bike + certain types of accessories, then the company got a bill itemised by employee name). Not only did we sell 20-odd extra bikes in two weeks, we also got paid the full amount 30 days later in one hit (which is always nice). The discount we offered was 35% on bikes, 20% on accessories.